# Bash TreeSize Script - improved output alignment

Tags: linux, bash, awk, directory, sizeof

Given the script below

```
#/bin/sh
echo
echo treesize of `pwd` at `date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
echo

du -k --max-depth=1 | sort -nr | awk '
BEGIN {
    split("KB,MB,GB,TB", Units, ",");
}

{
    u = 1;
    while ($1 >= 1024) {
            $1 = $1 / 1024;
            u += 1
    }

    $1 = sprintf("% *d%.1f %s", (7-length(sprintf("%.1f", $1))), 0, $1, Units[u]);
    print $0;
}
'
echo
```

Getting the following output:

```
 treesize of /home/jonathan at 2020-04-08 10:18:50

 0295.4 GB .
 0175.6 GB ./Documents
 0118.5 GB ./vmware
  047.9 MB ./Desktop
  032.0 KB ./Pictures
  012.0 KB ./Videos
   04.0 KB ./.Public
```

How do I get to remove the leading 0 and have spaces instead please?
Enjoy the script! Credits to someone on the internet :)

Comment: Why don't you just do: `$1 = sprintf("%8.1f %s", $1, Units[u]);`

Comment: thanks for optimizing this kvantour :) works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find the issue: replace 0 in the sprintf command with a " ".

```
#/bin/sh
echo
echo treesize of `pwd` at `date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
echo

du -k --max-depth=1 | sort -nr | awk '
BEGIN {
    split("KB,MB,GB,TB", Units, ",");
}

{
    u = 1;
    while ($1 >= 1024) {
            $1 = $1 / 1024;
            u += 1
    }

    $1 = sprintf("%8.1f %s", $1, Units[u]);
    print $0;
}'
echo
```

And now displays :

```
treesize of /home/jonathan at 2020-04-08 11:03:29

   295.5 GB .
   175.6 GB ./Documents
   118.5 GB ./vmware
  1003.7 MB ./.cache
   268.1 MB ./.config
    47.9 MB ./Desktop
    32.0 KB ./Pictures
    12.0 KB ./Videos
     4.0 KB ./.Templates
     4.0 KB ./.Public
     4.0 KB ./Music
     4.0 KB ./Downloads
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Use `sed`

```
sed 's#^[[:space:]]*0# #g'
```

`^` -- start of the line
`[[:space:]]` <- Space character
`*` <-- 0 or more occurence

```
#/bin/sh
echo
echo treesize of `pwd` at `date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
echo

du -k --max-depth=1 | sort -nr | awk '
BEGIN {
    split("KB,MB,GB,TB", Units, ",");
}

{
    u = 1;
    while ($1 >= 1024) {
            $1 = $1 / 1024;
            u += 1
    }

    $1 = sprintf("% *d%.1f %s", (7-length(sprintf("%.1f", $1))), 0, $1, Units[u]);
    print $0;
}' | sed 's#^[[:space:]]*0# #g'
echo
```

Comment: thanks for the input however that does a left align rather than a right alignment